# Trying to write sequentially named CSV files in r

Tags: r, csv

Apologies for what may be a very basic question. I have written an R code that analyses the flow of coronary artery bypass grafts.  I will have about 2000 unique measurements that need to be analysed.  I am intending to save each measurement with a number to give 2000 individual CSV files (1:2000).

I am trying to automate this naming process rather than individually changing the file name.  I am totally stuck on this and my attempts to extrapolate from previously asked questions about breaking up large data frames into multiple smaller, sequentially named .csv files have not gone anywhere.

e.g.

```
list<-list.files("file path")

lapply(seq_along(list), function(i) 
  write.csv(list[[i]], file=paste0(i, '.csv'), row.names=FALSE))
```

I would be very grateful if someone would be able to provide guidance as I imagine this should be easily remedied!

Many thanks in advance,

Campbell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the filenames using `list.files`, extract the number from the filenames and select the max number. Increment the number by 1 and write the next file.

```
filenames <- list.files("file path")
num <- max(readr::parse_number(basename(filenames)))
write.csv(data, paste0(num + 1, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I think I may not have been clear in my description.  I have yet to take the measurements so renaming files isn't quite what I am after.  I am trying to "write" the output from my R code into new CSV files.  As each new measurement is taken I want the file to be named as the next number in the sequence from the previous made files.

Comment: So you want to read the current files in your system, see the last one written and write one new file incrementing the number?

Comment: Absolutely correct, thank you so much for the understanding.  Also apologies for my poor previous explanation

Comment: How are the files named? Are they named `1.csv`, 2.csv` etc? Can you test my edited answer and see if it would work for you?

Comment: Hi Ronak, the files are indeed intended to be 1.csv, 2.csv etc.  I tried your code and it worked well but the file for your code (2.csv) was saved to an old working directory (definitely not my current wd and not the "file path" previously included.  put a short line of code in as follows:filenames <- list.files("/Users/campbell/Documents/CTSx/Masters/Haemodynamics study/R_output")
path_out<-"/Users/campbell/Documents/CTSx/Masters/Haemodynamics study/R_output"
num <- max(readr::parse_number(basename(filenames)))
write.csv(Export_DF, paste0(path_out, num + 1, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE)

Comment: cont... the file output for this is R_output2.csv which then unfortunately is not recongized by your fantastic strategy.  Apologies again for my ignorance but I wonder if this too had an easy solution

Comment: I think your `path_out` should be `path_out<-"/Users/campbell/Documents/CTSx/Masters/Haemodynamics study/R_output/"`. It should end with `/` so that `R_output` is considered as folder and not part of filename. Can you try that?

Comment: That works absolutely perfectly thank you so much! What a fantastic community here! I hope I become proficient at this to give back some day.